Shrinking Interval Property + what is equivalent to Nested Interval Property?
Shrinking Interval Property: Suppose $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dots$ are (bounded) closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with lengths decreasing to $0$. Then the intersection of the $I_n$'s is nonempty.
Nested Interval Property: Suppose $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dots$ are (bounded) closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Then the intersection of the $I_n$'s is nonempty.
Completeness Property: Suppose $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded above. Then there exists a number $c$, which is the least upper bound of $S$, such that every upper bound of $S$ is greater than or equal to $c$.
Archimedean Property: For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > x$. Equivalently, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n < x$.
In ordered fields, SIP + AP is equivalent to completeness. Completeness implies NIP. NIP implies SIP but not completeness. Is it possible to formulate a property such that SIP plus this property is equivalent to NIP, but this property by itself does not imply NIP?
